# How to do a BETWEEN merge the data.table way?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have two data.tables that are each 5-10GB in size. They look similar to the following.

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(
  person = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4),
  datetime = c(
    '2015-04-06 14:22:18',
    '2015-04-07 02:55:32',
    '2015-11-21 10:16:05',
    '2015-10-03 13:37:29',
    '2015-02-26 23:51:56',
    '2015-05-16 18:21:44',
    '2015-06-02 04:07:43',
    '2015-11-28 15:22:36',
    '2015-01-19 04:10:22',
    '2015-01-24 02:18:11'
  )
)

B <- data.table(
  person = c(1,1,3,4,4,5),
  datetime2 = c(
    '2015-04-06 14:24:59',
    '2015-11-28 15:22:36',
    '2015-06-02 04:07:43',
    '2015-01-19 06:10:22',
    '2015-01-24 02:18:18',
    '2015-04-06 14:22:18'
  )
)

A$datetime <- as.POSIXct(A$datetime)
B$datetime2 <- as.POSIXct(B$datetime2)
```

The idea is to find rows in B where the datetime is within 0-10 minutes of a matching row in A (matching is done by person) and mark them in A. The question is how can I do it most efficiently using data.table?

One plan is to join the two data tables based on [I]person[/I] only, then calculate the time difference and find rows where the time difference is between 0 and 600 seconds, and finally outer join the latter with A:

```
setkey(A,person)
AB <- A[B,.(datetime,
            datetime2,
            diff = difftime(datetime2, datetime, units = "secs"))
        , by = .EACHI]
M <- AB[diff < 600 & diff > 0]
setkey(A, person, datetime)
setkey(M, person, datetime)
M[A,]
```

Which gives us the correct result:

```
    person            datetime           datetime2     diff
 1:      1 2015-04-06 14:22:18 2015-04-06 14:24:59 161 secs
 2:      1 2015-04-07 02:55:32                <NA>  NA secs
 3:      1 2015-11-21 10:16:05                <NA>  NA secs
 4:      2 2015-10-03 13:37:29                <NA>  NA secs
 5:      3 2015-02-26 23:51:56                <NA>  NA secs
 6:      3 2015-05-16 18:21:44                <NA>  NA secs
 7:      3 2015-06-02 04:07:43                <NA>  NA secs
 8:      3 2015-11-28 15:22:36                <NA>  NA secs
 9:      4 2015-01-19 04:10:22                <NA>  NA secs
10:      4 2015-01-24 02:18:11 2015-01-24 02:18:18   7 secs
```

However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. Specifically, I am using `AB[diff < 600 & diff > 0]` which I assume will run a vector search not a binary search, but I cannot think of how to do it using a binary search.

Also, I am not sure if converting to `POSIXct` is the most efficient way of calculating time differences.

Any ideas on how to improve efficiency are high appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data.table's rolling join is perfect for this task:

```
B[, datetime := datetime2]
setkey(A,person,datetime)
setkey(B,person,datetime)
B[A,roll=-600]

   person           datetime2   datetime
 1:      1 2015-04-06 14:24:59 1428319338
 2:      1                  NA 1428364532
 3:      1                  NA 1448090165
 4:      2                  NA 1443868649
 5:      3                  NA 1424983916
 6:      3                  NA 1431789704
 7:      3 2015-06-02 04:07:43 1433207263
 8:      3                  NA 1448713356
 9:      4                  NA 1421629822
10:      4 2015-01-24 02:18:18 1422055091
```

The only difference with your expected output is that it checks timedifference as less or equal to 10 minutes (<=). If that is bad for you you can just delete equal matches

Comment: No need to unclass. Should work just fine with `POSIXct` (since it's a numeric value with an attribute, as eddi mentions).